# Can't find the bug on my site

Tags: html, css

Here is my site:

http://mihalko.eu/download/

Why is the catalogue in the 2nd row floated to the right, and not to the left (the left side is blank - only in the 2nd row)?

I added some more downloads with firebug, and everything is fine, except the 2nd row.

[Picture http://d.pr/a8VQ](http://d.pr/a8VQ)

Comment: Just a tip that url shortening links might seem like the way to go to save display space or something but it is also fishy. For all we know it's a sweepstakes link or a rick roll. You should edit those and link directly to your site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because the 1st box has a height of 103px while the 2nd one has a height of 102px, therefore the next float comes in at the lowest height.  make the first image 102px solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add

---

after each two entries, hr should have clear:both, width 100%

You can also pack each two entries to separate div

Comment: that's not necessary.  If all the images are the same height they should float properly.  He only needs to clear it if he doesn't want the next row to float.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you want to have a  with a class of "clear: both" in order to display properly. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

`

```
.clearboth {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

<div class="download-box">
    <div class="download-box-image">
        <a href="http://mihalko.eu/downloads/slovkolex_katalog_2011.pdf" title="Slovkolex katalóg"><img alt="Slovkolex" src="http://mihalko.eu/image/data/download/slovkolex.jpg" width="140"></a></div>
    <div class="download-box-text">
        <div class="nazov">
            Katalóg Slovkolex</div>
        <div class="typ">
            *.pdf</div>
        26 236 kB</div>
</div>
<div class="download-box">
    <div class="download-box-image">
        <a href="http://mihalko.eu/downloads/DEMA_dealerbook_2012.pdf" title="Dema 2012"><img alt="Dema 2012" src="http://mihalko.eu/image/data/download/Dema 2012.jpg" width="140" style="opacity: 1; "></a></div>
    <div class="download-box-text">
        <div class="nazov">
            Katalóg Dema 2012</div>
        <div class="typ">
            *.pdf</div>
        32 116 kB</div>
</div>

<!-- HERES THE CHANGE -->
<div class="clearboth"></div>

<div class="download-box">
    <div class="download-box-image">
        <a href="http://mihalko.eu/do`enter code here`wnloads/slovkolex_katalog_2011.pdf" title="Slovkolex katalóg"><img alt="Slovkolex" src="http://mihalko.eu/image/data/download/slovkolex.jpg" width="140"></a></div>
    <div class="download-box-text">
        <div class="nazov">
            Katalóg Slovkolex</div>
        <div class="typ">
            *.pdf</div>
        26 236 kB</div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

@thenetimp is correct. Change the height of the very first block of 102.

```
style="height: 102px;"
```

should fix the problem.

Note: It is be design, the float will take the next available *highest* place where it can fit itself. One pixel is a difference therefore it fits itself a little higher.

Answer (score 0):

```
.download-box {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 15px 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 295px;
    height: 104px;
}
```